# Relating Normal Curvature to Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

> Let $Σ$ be a regular surface in $\Bbb{R_3}$ with Gauss curvature larger than
>   zero. Given any regular curve $C$ contained in $Σ$ and point $p$ on $C$, let
>   $κ1$ and $κ2$ be the principal curvatures of $Σ$ at $p$ and $κ(p)$ the curvature
>   of $C$ at $p$. Show that the following inequality is true $$κ(p) ≥ \text{min}\{|κ1|, |κ2|\}$$

How would I go about solving this question. I don't really know how to relate regular curvature to normal curvature.

Comment: I know that but how does that relate to the actual curvature itself? I don't think i'm seeing the connection.

Comment: There is in fact some confusion here. You might for future reference look at [Meusnier's Theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Meusnier_theorem). In particular, $k_N = \kappa\cos\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between the surface normal and the principal normal of the curve.

Comment: @VishwaIyer You're welcome. You might also find my differential geometry text helpful as a resource. You can click on the link in my profile and download it.

Comment: Any hint to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

$\vert \kappa(p)\vert \geqslant \min\{| \kappa_1(p)|,| \kappa_2(p)|\} $ !!!

### Probably this can be regarded as a hint:

To connect the curvature at a random direction with the principle curvature at the principle directions, it is very convenient to seek help from Euler's formula, $k_1(p)\sin^2\theta +k_2(p)\cos^2 \theta=k_\vec v(p)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the random direction $\vec v$ and the principal direction. To derive this formula, you have to use second fundamental form $k_\vec v(p)=\langle-\mathrm dN_p(\vec v),\vec v\rangle$. And regarding that the second fundamental form is a quadratic form, you can find an orthogonal basis(i.e. pricipal directions, say $\vec e_1,\vec e_2$) where $k_\vec v(p)=\pmatrix{\sin\theta&\cos\theta}\pmatrix{k_1&0\\0&k_2}\pmatrix{\sin\theta\\\cos\theta},\vec v=\sin\theta\cdot\vec e_1+\cos\theta\cdot\vec e_2$.